# Apply css styles to all elements that become/are disabled

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to apply css styles to all elements that are/become disabled

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input type:checkbox").attr("disabled", true).css("border","1px solid #000000");
});
```

doesn't seem to work. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selectors

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("input:checkbox:disabled").css("border","1px solid #000000"); 
});
```

Also it would be better if you add a class for that instead of applying css directly. Something like

```
.disabledcheckbx { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("input:checkbox:disabled").addClass("disabledcheckbx");
});
```

Comment: Also, this will automatically apply to any checkboxes that become disabled as your page works, thus it fully answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

That will attempt to *set* every checkbox's `disabled` attribute to true.

You want this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox:disabled').css('border', '1px solid #000;');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

styling checkboxes is not widely supported by most browser as you can see in this [test](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox//).

but if you really want it, you may try this [plugin](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/)